# Index is out of range: JDBC SqlServer exception

Tags: sql-server, linux, hadoop, jdbc, sqoop

I am using Sqoop to import data from SQL server to local HDFS. I am using a simple free form query to pull some 10 rows from the table. Below is the sqoop command that I execute from the terminal:

```
sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://xx.xx.xx.xx;username=xx;password=xxxxx;database=DBName' --query "SELECT top 10 OrderID from DJShopcart_OrderItems where \$CONDITIONS"  --split-by "OrderID" --target-dir  /work/gearpurchase
```

When I execute this from my local machine, I get the following exception:

> Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index
>   2 is out of range.    at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:191)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.verifyValidColumnIndex(SQLServerResultSet.java:543)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getterGetColumn(SQLServerResultSet.java:2066)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getValue(SQLServerResultSet.java:2099)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getValue(SQLServerResultSet.java:2084)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getInt(SQLServerResultSet.java:2327)
>     at
>   org.apache.sqoop.lib.JdbcWritableBridge.readInteger(JdbcWritableBridge.java:52)
>     at
>   com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.JdbcWritableBridge.readInteger(JdbcWritableBridge.java:53)
>     at QueryResult.readFields(QueryResult.java:105)     at
>   org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBRecordReader.nextKeyValue(DBRecordReader.java:244)

If I import 2 columns, the exception says index 3 is out of range.

I checked the [SQLServerResultSet](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerResultSet.java) class documentation also, to understand what could be the cause of exception but to no use. Only got more confused with concepts like Client-Side Cursor vs Server-Side Cursor

No matter what I try I can't get this simple free form query to import data from SQL server.

```
Sqoop version : 1.4.6 
Hadoop : 2.7.3
Machine : Ubuntu 16.04
```

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> If I import 2 columns, the exception says index 3 is out of range.

Then the fault lies with SQOOP.

```
at org.apache.sqoop.lib.JdbcWritableBridge.readInteger(JdbcWritableBridge.java:52)
```

As it's passing 3 as an argument to

```
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getInt(SQLServerResultSet.java:2327)
```

When the result only contains 2 columns, and the valid column indexes are 1 and 2.